# Image not found on amazon s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just made work the paperclip with amazon s3. 
I can upload successfully an image.

when I am trying to render the image

```
<%= image_tag @client.image.url(:thumb) %>
```

I am not able

```
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/clients/images/000/000/009/thumb/id1_001.jpg?1448466990">
```

Image not found
When I am visiting the url

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/clients/images/000/000/009/thumb/id1_001.jpg?1448466990
```

I am getting a message

```
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the  specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
<Bucket>mybucket</Bucket>
<Endpoint>mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
```

How can I configure paperclip to use the right path ?

Comment: Could you show us how you configured paperclip?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, and by setting correct host name of S3 for paperclip solved my problem:

I assume you must config your S3 credentials some where, and make the config like this:

```
paperclip_options = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :s3_host_name => PLACE YOUR BUCKET HOST NAME HERE,
          :bucket => XXX,
          :access_key_id => YYY,
          :secret_access_key => ZZZ
      },
      :s3_protocol => :https
}

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update(paperclip_options)
```

Please note the option: `s3_host_name` is the key to solve your problem :)

Comment: yes this partial helped, I need to remove the bucket completely from the url.

Comment: what do you mean by "remove the bucket completely from the url"?